# How can we insert multiple texts and paragraphs in google docs using google docs api with php?

Tags: php, google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to insert more the one texts in google docs with multiple paragraph contents and also want to style them. I also followed this link https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request but I am unable to achieve this.

```
$requests [] = new Google_Service_Docs_Request(
[
    'insertText' => [
        'text' => 'Sample1\n',
        'location' => [
            'index' => 1
        ]
    ]
],
  [
    'insertText' => [
      'text' => 'sample2\n',
      'location' => [
        'index' => 9
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    'updateParagraphStyle' => [
      'range' => [
        'startIndex' => 1,
        'endIndex' => 8
      ],
      'paragraphStyle' => [
        'namedStyleType' => 'HEADING_1'
      ],
      'fields' => 'namedStyleType'
    ]
  ],
  [
    'updateParagraphStyle' => [
      'range' => [
        'startIndex' => 9,
        'endIndex' => 17
      ],
      'paragraphStyle' => [
        'namedStyleType' => 'NORMAL_TEXT'
      ],
      'fields' => 'namedStyleType'
  ]
  ],
  [
    'updateTextStyle' => [
      'range' => [
        'startIndex' => 9,
        'endIndex' => 16
      ],
      'textStyle' => [
        'link' => [
          'url' => 'https://www.google.com'
        ]
      ],
      'fields' => 'link'
    ]
  ]
);
$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(array(
    'requests' => $requests
));

$response = $service->documents->batchUpdate($documentId, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

I am doing in this way and getting this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid requests[0]: No request set.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid requests[0]: No request set.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this. It would be a great help and i need it in PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sample1\n` of `'text' => 'Sample1\n',` is converted to `Sample1\\n`. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. In this case, how about the following modification using `PHP_EOL`?

> `PHP_EOL`: The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform.

#### Modified script:

```php
$requests = [
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
        'insertText' => [
            'text' => 'Sample1' . PHP_EOL, // Modified
            'location' => [
                'index' => 1
            ]
        ]
    ]),
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
        'insertText' => [
            'text' => 'Sample2' . PHP_EOL, // Modified
            'location' => [
                'index' => 9 // Modified
            ]
        ]
    ])
];
```

or, please enclose the text by the double quotes as follows.

```php
$requests = [
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
        'insertText' => [
            'text' => "Sample1\n", // Modified
            'location' => [
                'index' => 1
            ]
        ]
    ]),
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
        'insertText' => [
            'text' => "Sample2\n", // Modified
            'location' => [
                'index' => 9 // Modified
            ]
        ]
    ])
];
```

- By this modification, `'Sample1' . PHP_EOL` and `"Sample1\n"` are used as `Sample\n`. By this, I thought that your goal can be achieved.
- In this case, `index` of the 2nd request is `9` that you have used in the first script.

#### References:

- [Predefined Constants for PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)
- [Single quoted](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

  > To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (). To specify a literal backslash, double it (\). All other instances of backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: this means that the other escape sequences you might be used to, such as \r or \n, will be output literally as specified rather than having any special meaning.
- [Double quoted](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

  > If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret the following escape sequences for special characters:

Comment: Hii , i am so glad that you replied me, but none of the above solutions is working. "sample1\n" or 'Sample1' . PHP_EOL  none of this working. It's not inserting on next line. It's inserting on the same single line. Can you please share me what is the other solution for this. How we can insert in on the next line.

Comment: @Taniya Halder Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, when I tested both modified scripts, the script works. 2 paragraphs are created. So I cannot replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. In order to correctly understand your situation of `but none of the above solutions is working. "sample1\n" or 'Sample1' . PHP_EOL none of this working.`, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. It was my bad that i did not saw the index modified part. Its working fine completely. Thankyou so much.

Comment: @Taniya Halder Thank you for replying and checking it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is caused by the construction of the batch request. The request array must contain a number of instances of `Google_Service_Docs_Request`.

Try change this:

```php
$requests [] = new Google_Service_Docs_Request(
[
    'insertText' => [
        'text' => 'Sample1\n',
        'location' => [
            'index' => 1
        ]
    ]
],
  [
    'insertText' => [
      'text' => 'sample2\n',
      'location' => [
        'index' => 9
      ]
    ]
  ],
```

To this:

```php
$requests = [
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
    'insertText' => [
        'text' => 'Sample1\n',
        'location' => [
            'index' => 1
        ]
    ]
    ]),
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
    'insertText' => [
      'text' => 'sample2\n',
      'location' => [
        'index' => 9
      ]
    ])
];
```

And after proceed as follows:

```php
$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(['requests' => $requests]);
$result = $service->documents->batchUpdate($documentId, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

##### Documentation:

- [PHP Google Docs API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/docs/v1/php/latest/)

Comment: ,Thanks for sharing your answer, it worked for inserting both the texts like you shown above but can you tell me why "\n" is not working and how indexing is defined in this.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with `\n` is not working? Maybe you want to review [this](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#inserttextrequest): `Inserting a newline character will implicitly create a new Paragraph at that index.`

Comment: Actually i want to insert my next text in a new line. How can i achieve that.

Comment: As I say in my previous comment, adding `\n` should work, what do you see instead?

Comment: It is inserting my texts like this in the google docs     Sample1n\sample2\n   in one single line. "\n" is not working

Comment: Seems that you find a bug. I reported it  at [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/218301789).